# ¿Como obtener el neto total máximo de la resta entre dos tablas?

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta query que me trae el total de me gusta de cada usuario y de no me gusta del mes anterior y los resta, y con esto me trae el total neto de cada usuario, para después poner un `LIMIT 1`al final del query y me diga cual es el que mayor total neto tiene, pero al correr el query me trae al mayor total neto pero negativo y debería de traer el mayor positivo, no he encontrado como poder traerme ese usuario.

Este es el query:

```
       SELECT T.nom_usuario,
          SUM(T.total) AS total_neto
          FROM (
              SELECT  nom_usuario,
              COUNT(1) AS total
              FROM megusta A
              WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
              AND MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
              GROUP BY A.nom_usuario HAVING COUNT(1) > 0

              UNION

              SELECT  nom_usuario,
              COUNT(1) * -1  AS total
              FROM nomegusta B
              WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
              AND MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
              GROUP BY B.nom_usuario HAVING COUNT(1) > 0
          ) T
          GROUP BY T.nom_usuario
          HAVING MAX(T.total) > 1
```

Esto es lo que me da como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El usuario que debería obtener como el mayor total neto es cesaropp.

Comment: Agrega al final  un  `ORDER BY total_neto DESC`, para que así funcione el `LIMIT`

Comment: en la ultima linea debe ser HAVING SUM(T.total) > 1 y al inicio creo que debería ser SELECT T.nom_usuario MAX(SUM(T.total))....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo que a veces no tenemos claro, es que las bases de datos NO nos aseguran ningún orden en particular a menos claro, que se lo indiquemos.

Si quieres la primer fila de una consulta mediante el `LIMIT 1` debes asegurarte que ésta, sea verdaderamente la que te interesa, en este caso la de del máximo total, para lo cual, debería ordenar la salida así:

```
SELECT T.nom_usuario,
       MAX(SUM(T.total)) AS total_neto <--para obtener el máximo valor
       FROM (
             ...
       ) T
       GROUP BY T.nom_usuario
       HAVING SUM(T.total) > 1
       ORDER BY total_neto DESC
       LIMIT 1;
```

`ORDER BY total_neto DESC` te asegura que la primer fila será aquella de mayor `total_neto`

Comment: Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho es la segunda vez que me sacas de dudas, la verdad gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En la ultima linea debe ser HAVING SUM(T.total) > 1 y al inicio debería ser SELECT T.nom_usuario MAX(SUM(T.total)) , quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT T.nom_usuario,
          MAX(SUM(T.total)) AS total_neto <--para obtener el máximo valor
          FROM (
              SELECT  nom_usuario,
              COUNT(1) AS total
              FROM megusta A
              WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
              AND MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
              GROUP BY A.nom_usuario HAVING COUNT(1) > 0

              UNION

              SELECT  nom_usuario,
              COUNT(1) * -1  AS total
              FROM nomegusta B
              WHERE YEAR(fecha) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
              AND MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
              GROUP BY B.nom_usuario HAVING COUNT(1) > 0
          ) T
          GROUP BY T.nom_usuario
          HAVING SUM(T.total) > 1 <--para obtener la sumas positivas o mayores que 1
```

Quizá no deberías utilizar el limit, porque podría dars el caso en que mas de un usuario tenga la misma cantidad neta.